# Laravel !isset is returning undefined index, while trying to ::create an address

Tags: laravel

While trying to edit a user without address information, it returns undefined index while !isset is being used.

```
  $regions = DB::table("regions")->pluck("name","id");
    $address = Address::where('id', $request->id)->with('region')->first();
    $data = $this->data->getEditClient($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    // dd($data);

    if(!isset($address)){
        $address = Address::create([
            'street_name'   => $input['street_name'], 
            'house_number'  => $input['house_number'], 
            'postcode'      => $input['postcode'], 
            'city_id'       => $input['city_id'], 
            'country_id'    => $input['country_id'], 
            'region_id'     => $input['region_id'] 
        ]);


        $address =  new Address;
        //associate address with user
        $address->user()->associate($user);

        $address->save();
        return redirect('/client')->with('Succes', 'Client has been editted');

    }
```

It should go on, and create an address since it is not set. What am i missing here.

Comment: please post us the exact eroor trace

Comment: ErrorException in UserController.php line 56:
Undefined index: street_name

Comment: which line has number 56 in UserController.php ?

Comment: 'street_name'   => $input['street_name'],

Comment: it refers to a edit form with the name="street_name"

Comment: this mean that browser not pass street_name when send request. put `dd($request->all());` before that line and show us output

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "K87K572iviFxdXZXhZDqZyG5dp1KJ5ZpByJHoWaf"
  "table" => "client"
  "selected" => "16"
  "contractID" => "0"
]

Comment: Its, when i trying to enter the edit form, it returns that error since it has no input at all, im trying to make that input when i am in the edit form

Comment: so your problem is not in code you show us in question but in passing parameters during request sending.

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(!isset($address))` to `if(!$address)` and remove `$address =  new Address;` in that if (because you create it few lines earlier).

### Update

Info from comments: line number 56 in UserController.php is `'street_name'   => $input['street_name'],` this mean that browser not pass street_name when send request. The problem is probably in frontend part of your code.

Comment: Still returns Undefined index: street_name

Comment: @Michael you're missing the `street_name` in your `$input`

Answer (score 0):

try to update your code to this

```
if(!$address){
    $address = Address::create([
        'street_name'   => ($input['street_name'])? $input['street_name'] : null, 
        'house_number'  => ($input['house_number'])? $input['house_number'] : null, 
        'postcode'      => ($input['postcode'])? $input['postcode'] : null, 
        'city_id'       => ($input['city_id'])? $input['city_id'] : null, 
        'country_id'    => ($input['country_id'])? $input['country_id'] : null, 
        'region_id'     => ($input['region_id'])? $input['region_id'] : null
    ]);

    //associate address with user
    $address->user()->associate($user);

    $address->save();
    return redirect('/client')->with('Succes', 'Client has been editted');

}
```

NOTE: The error you are getting is pointing to the fact that the `street_name` variable is not passed. This solution would just bypass that and set default values in empty cases. If you wish to set the `street_name` you should check your client-side and ensure the variable is spelt correctly and passed

Comment: could you update the question, with a copy of the complete <form> tag from your front-end